# Create meeting with exhibitors and participants rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, devise, model, controller

I'm new on Ror,
I would like to add in my app a feature where my users can join different meetings created by an admin, as exhibitors (if sellers) or participants (if clients). 
I'm using device and I distinguish my clients (futur participants) from my sellers (futur exhibitors) with an enum.
I'm spending time on this.. and unfortunately can't succeed to do this feature. Thks you for your help.
Here is my code:

Meeting.rb

```
class Meeting < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :start_time, presence: true

end
```

User.rb

```
  has_many :meetings
```

Meetings Controller:

```
def participate
    @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
    if user.client?
      @participant = @meeting << current_user
      @participant.save
    elsif user.seller?
      @exhibitor = @meeting << current_user
      @exhibitor.save
    end
  end

  def show
    @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
    @exhibitors = User.all.participate
  end
```

meetings/show.html.erb:

```
<strong>Evenement:</strong><%= @meeting.name %><br>
détails<%= @meeting.details %><br>
le: <%= @meeting.start_time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %><br>
adresse:<%= @meeting.address %><br>
Nombre d'exposants: <%= @exhibitors.count %><br>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<% if current_user.seller? %>
<%= link_to participate_path, class:"btn btn-info" do %>
Reserver un stand
<% end %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :meetings
get 'participate' => 'meetings#participate'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you may want to change your routes to something like:

```
  resources :meetings do
    post :participate
  end
```

This will generate a URI like:

`/meetings/:meeting_id/participate`

Then for your method, you can instead of pushing the user into the meeting, do it the other way around by pushing the meeting into the user, so in your `participate` method:

```
def participate
 meeting = Meeting.find(params[:meeting_id])
 current_user.meetings << meeting
end
```

As you can see you don't need the instance variable, or at least for what I can see, but in case you need it, just bring it back.

Comment: Hi Kurenn, I tried your way.  and even this way:     def participate
   meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
   current_user.meetings << meeting
   if  current_user.meetings.save
    render :index, notice: "You are registered to this meeting"
  else
    render :participate
  end
end         I have the following error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MeetingsController#participate
Couldn't find Meeting with 'id'=

Comment: Ohh I see, than I missed read or something, but to understand the participate method is in charge just to push the meeting into the meetings array, save it and then redirect to the index?

Comment: Great @kurenn that works!  ans d the link to is: <%= link_to "Reserver un stand", meeting_participate_path(@meeting), method: :post %>